# Direct proof regarding extension of functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm supposed to give a direct proof of the following theorem (Theorem 4.3-3 in Kreyszig) which states:

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $x_0\neq 0$ be an arbitrary element of $X$. Then there exists a bounded linear functional $\hat{f}$ on $X$ such that

$$||\hat{f}||=1,\ \ \ \hat{f}(x_0)=||x_0||.$$

There is a proof of this theorem in the book but I'm asked to consider the case of $X=\mathcal{H}$ ($X$ being a Hilbert space) and to prove it directly by giving an explicit definition of a suitable functional $\hat{f}$.

I have some difficulties trying to come up with an explicit definition of such a functional $\hat{f}$. I've tried using Riesz's representation theorem to construct a bounded linear functional, i.e., a functional of the form

$$\hat{f}(x)=\langle x,x_0\rangle\ \forall x\in\mathcal{H}.$$

Obviously this does not satisfy the conditions, but I have a feeling it's something of this form I need to construct. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary obstruction to the Hahn-Banach Theorem in general is a decomposition $X=X_1\oplus X_2,$ where you've already defined the functional on, say $X_1$ - this is the question of "what do I do with *the rest* of $X$=" - and what even *is* the rest of $X$?

Thankfully, in Hilbert space, given a subspace, you have a natural "remainder" - the orthogonal complement.

So, in your case, you have the functional $f$ on $X_1=\textrm{span}_{\mathbb{C}} \{x_0\}$ given by $f(\lambda x_0)=\lambda ||x_0||$, which clearly satisfies the given condtions on $X_1$. Now, if $X_2=X_1^{\perp},$ then we can define $\hat{f}$ on $X_2$ to be the $0$-functional, and now, for a general vector $x\in \mathcal{H},$ we now have a unique decomposition $x=\lambda x_0+y$ with $y\in X_2$ via the orthogonal projection.

Thus, $\hat{f}(x)=\lambda||x_0||$ works.

Of course we can do this via the Riesz representation theorem as well. Your attempt is almost this. Our $\hat{f}$ is actually the functional $x\mapsto \langle x,\frac{x_0}{||x_0||}\rangle$.

I just wanted to highlight that there is something very general that works here, once you have a direct sum decomposition of your Banach Space.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the more general view of how one would go about doing this. It does make a lot of sense!